# Remove (Synchronized) status on database in Object Explorer for SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssms, availability-zone

We've recently implemented Availability Zones in AWS and one big downside right now is this huge eyesore. When looking at the databases in the Object Explorer for SQL Server Management Studio, the database names look like this:

- Database 1 (Synchronized)
- Database 2 (Synchronized)
- Database 3 (Synchronized)
- Database etc (Synchronized)

It actually makes things more difficult to find. I've checked the settings for object explorer, and I'm just not seeing anything to turn that off. Every google search goes into detail about what these statuses mean, and how to get availability zones set up, but not how to remove these statuses from constantly being there.

Comment: In short- no; afaik there is no option to hide this, in SSMS this is standard for databases involved in availability groups or zones and will show synchronized or synchronizing, depending on the sync / async config.

Comment: That is such a bummer :(

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that what you're seeing is the status of that database as it relates to Availability Groups (which can be implemented in conjunction with AWS AZs but the latter are not required). As a commenter has suggested, there doesn't seem to be a way to get rid of these statuses in Object Explorer. But you do have options to address what seems to be your concern ("It actually makes things more difficult to find").

1. If you right-click on the "Databases" folder in Object Explorer, there is an option to filter. Specify either the database name in full or part. Boom... filtered list.
2. Select the "Databases" folder in Object Explorer and hit F7 (or go to the View → Object Explorer Details). This will open a new tab where the database's AG status hasn't been appended onto the name. Note - you can also filter here!